# Add Link to WCF RIA Services from non Silverlight project

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I have a default Class Library project, which I want to link to WCF RiA Services, located on other ASP.NET project.
I know how to create link to RIA Services from WCF RIA Service Class Library - but it is Silverlight project, which use Silverlight mscorelib.dll and other Silverlight environment libraries. **How to create link from server (default .net class library) project?** (Server to Server link)

I try to create link to WCF Service In Visual Studio2010 by "Add Service Reference" with URL:
http://localhost:52878/Services/MyProject-Web-Services-MyService.svc
but I get error: 401 Unauthorized
At the same time I can view this service in browser (IE, Chrome, FF with input AD credentials)
IIS requres Windows Authentication. Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can this! - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707336(v=VS.91).aspx